# How to delete lines from file that doesnt match pattern or arent in a certain range

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep

I have a file.txt looking something like this:

```
{lat: 41.074294, lng:14.274297},
{lat: 41.074394, lng:14.274397},▒
{lat: 41.074494," lng:14.274497},
{lat: 41.07494, lng:14.274597},
lat: 41.074394, lng:14.274397},
{lat: 41.074494, lng:14.274497},
{lat: 41.074594, lng:14.274597},
{lat: 0.00000, lng:0.0000},
{lat: 46.074294, lng:14.274297},
```

How can I delete all lines which does not contain the following pattern:

```
{lat: xx.xxxxxx, lng:xx.xxxxxx},
```

or that have to much difference to the other lines, like the last two lines? Probably grep or sed can do this, but I am not sure how to use them in this situation.

So the output should be like this:

```
{lat: 41.074294, lng:14.274297},
{lat: 41.074494, lng:14.274497},
{lat: 41.074594, lng:14.274597},
```

Comment: What about last line (`{lat: 46.074294, lng:14.274297},`)?

Comment: the latitiude coordinate has a too big difference 46 in comparison to 41.

Comment: @TimGelb, you can't say like have a too big difference. Its better if you provide a range within which you accept the difference(in numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep '^{lat: [0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\{6\}, lng:[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]\{6\}},$' file
```

Speaking like shouldn't have too big difference is too broad to answer. Being specific to your question, it can be done like:

```
grep '^{lat: [4][0-2]\.[0-9]\{6\}, lng:[1][3-5]\.[0-9]\{6\}},$' file
```

Comment: perfect thank you very much